# Read chunked HTTP in .Net

Tags: chunked-encoding

I'm trying to write a VB.net client that reads HTTP chunked data. The chunks contain additional information that I need to use.
I've already figured out that I can't use the HTTPWebResponse, since it hides the optional tags.
So, the way I understand it, I need to use a TCPClient, send the HTTP request through it, and then parse the response.
My question at this point is how do I create and send the HTTP request, especially as HTTPWebRequest is not serializable.

Any help, including an indication of a better way to do this, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you#re going to use TCPClient, then you're going to have to do the request by hand. Fortunately, HTTP is a reasonably easy to do. Just write the headers you need to send delimited by /n/r.

You'll probably want/need to read up on the HTTP spec.